# How to find the direct child using this selector?

Tags: javascript, jquery, this

I have this little code:

```
$("ul#mainnav > li").hover(function(){
   $("ul#mainnav > li > a").slideUp();
})
```

I just don't know the right syntax for selecting the direct child `<a>` using `$(this)`
What I used is this, and I think its wrong...

```
$(this).find("> a")
```

Thank you.

Comment: You have an extra quote after `this`

Comment: When you say "direct child", what do you mean? The first child? What if there are more than one descendents?

Comment: The direct children are <a> and <ul>. What I only want is the direct <a>. Because inside the <ul> there's a <li> <a>. I don't want to target the another <a>.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For starters, you have an extra quote. Remove the quote after `this`. Like this:

```
$(this).find("> a")
```

Admittedly I've never used selectors for this case, so I can't comment about why it's not working. Instead, I'd recommend using `children()` which is usually faster and, IMHO, clearer.

```
$(this).children('a');
```

But if you really want to use a string selector, this should work:

```
$('> a', this)
```

Note that the [jquery docs](http://api.jquery.com/child-selector/) say that the latter code will be deprecated at some point, so use with caution.  I'd still recommend using `children()`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `$(this).children("a:first")` if you just want the first a tag as well